# select if and update issue

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

Am using this sql to do an update on duplicate key

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mlm_settings` WHERE `key` = 'notify_type' AND `user_id`=7 >0 )
  UPDATE mlm_settings SET value='2' WHERE user_id = 7
ELSE
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `mlm_settings` (`key`, `value`,`user_id`) VALUES ('notify_type', '2',7)
END
```

by i get an sql error in mysql saying

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
`mlm_settings` WHERE `key` = 'notify_type' AND `user_id' at line 1
```

i can't figure what is the cause of the error, as the names of the tables are valid and the values are of the same data type

what could be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `IF` statements in stored procedures, not normal queries.

If there's a unique index on `(key, user_id)` in the table, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO mlm_settings (`key`, value, user_id) VALUES ('notify_type', '2', 7)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = '2';
```

Comment: i created a unique index for `(key, user_id)` as  you mentioned and used your solution, how can i use this for multiple inserts, such as `insert into table (c1) values('1'),('2'), etc`

Answer (score 1):

IF control block cannot be used OUTSIDE of functions. Try this:-

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(
             SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mlm_settings` WHERE `key` = 'notify_type' AND `user_id`=7 >0), 1, 0)
```

Comment: does this insert if there is an entry found

Comment: i already did, it gave me 1, how do i incorporate with the sql i wrote above

Comment: Its simple declare a variable check if the variable value is 1 then update it else insert it. Updating in my answer as well!!

Comment: is this using this a a normal query or in a stored procedure?